# Post custom Data value in The Events Calendar plugin

Tags: plugins, customization

```
<select name="e_brand" id="e_brand" class="e_brand" required>
    <option value="">Select Brand</option>
    <?php
    global $wpdb;
    $query="SELECT id,post_title FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type='brands' AND post_status='publish'";
    $result=mysqli_query($conn,$query);
    $check_users=mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if($check_users > 0){
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['post_title']; ?></option>
            <?php
        }
    } ?>
</select>
```

I have created custom dropdown which bind brand to the product in `event-meta-box.php` in ***The Event Calendar Plugin***. How can I post the value of product and brand in `meta_key` and `meta_value` in database (e.g. `meta_key` is `Brand` and `meta_value` is `brandvalue`). On which file I have to write post method to insert data in meta value column in the database. In which file, `Eventstartdate`, `EVentenddate`, `EventTimezone` and all field value are posted and saved in the database…? or there any other method to post the data.

Beacuse through Advanced custom field it insert value of brand in meta value. But I want to do it manually

I also writen jquery and ajax to bind the prooduct with brand, but how can i post that value in meta key and meta value and also update it. If you have solution,please provide me.. –

Please help me as soon as possible

Comment: Can you include the code you have so far? You mention you built a metabox with a dropdown, I take it the problem is figuring out how to save and persist that data between post saves/updates via post meta? Also have you considered that a custom taxonomy named `Brand` might actually be a better choice? Especially if you're intending to display posts by their brand or allow filtering/querying

Comment: <select name="e_brand" id="e_brand" class="e_brand" required>
       <option value="">Select Brand</option>
                           <?php global $wpdb;
        $query="SELECT id,post_title FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type='brands' AND post_status='publish'";
        $result=mysqli_query($conn,$query);
      $check_users=mysqli_num_rows($result);
      if($check_users > 0){while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ ?>
  <option value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['post_title']; ?></option><?php  }} ?></select>

Comment: Thanks for reply Tom. I also writen jquery and ajax to bind the prooduct with brand, but how can i post that value in meta key and meta value and also update it. If you have solution,please provide me..

Comment: Can you add it to your question via the edit link? It's unreadable in a comment

Comment: Thanks for Replying TOm. I have added.i am not able to add code.how can i add..?

Comment: There's a link named `edit` at the bottom of your question, you can click that, copy paste the code in and save. Don't forget to format it as code

Comment: As an aside, is this a plugin of your own making? Or are you trying to modify somebody elses plugin?

Comment: I am modifing The Event calendar plugin .

Comment: Hi Tom, Please Reply

Comment: Hello! I'm not a paid employee, I'm a random internet person doing things in my free time, tbh I'm inclined to close this as out of scope, you should be referring to the official docs of that plugin and their developer support. Neither me or most users here are experts in this plugin, and your question on closer inspection is very involved